# Using Fabric - digits for mobile number authentication

Tags: twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I have some specific questions -

- How is digits for signup/login via mobile number?
- Is it trustworthy(I have read that twitter have used fabric as a data collecting mechanism in the past)?
- What are the prospects that it will be free forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Yes, [Digits](https://get.digits.com) gives your mobile app users with simple phone number
  authentication.
- Yes, it is trustworthy, [Fabric is now part of Google](https://fabric.io/blog/fabric-joins-google) and Google is what your
  know.
- Yes, it is free of cost.
  https://twittercommunity.com/t/is-digits-is-completely-free/64909

Comment: Thanks Abhishek !! Could you please share your pros and cons of using digits (If you have used it). ?

Comment: https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-get-started-twitters-fabric/how-to/2014/11/10

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly Looking for that